# Fast spatial search algorithm/package

Tags: algorithm, geospatial, spatial

I have a dataset which has spatial objects (the red blobs in the picture below) that cover a number pixels or grid points - but has irregular shapes. I have another dataset which consists of points with 2D coordinates and I want to know whether each point in this dataset is within a certain distance from any pixel of any of the spatial objects. The main problem I have is that I have to explicitly look into each object struct to find its location and pixels. Is there a way for me to index the spatial information of the data such that I can perform this search more efficiently? Right now, I am doing it brute force, where given a point from the second dataset I have to loop through each object, check its location, check the location of its pixels, and then test if any one pixel is within a distance X from the point. I am using MATLAB but if there are any packages I could use in any language that would be great.

[image]

Comment: Have you read this [post and answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52244/calculating-distance-from-points-to-different-class-in-raster)? Also, QGIS has some nice tools and plugins that could help you. If not, have you looked at the range of spatial analysis packages available for R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many spatial indexing solutions, [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [r-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), and they are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database). There are also tools with built-in tools like [QGIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QGIS) and [GRASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASS_GIS). There are also heavy handed solution like [PostGIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostGIS) if you have lots of data.

However, looking at your image, and since you state that your objects are already rasterized, can you convert you objects image above to a binary image? Where your objects are 1 and background is 0? If your distance is a constant, then you could [dilate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) your binary image by that size. Then to do a lookup all you have to do is rasterize your test point and see if it is 1 or 0. If your objects or distance threshold are varying in your problem then I would use one of the spatial indexes listed above.